# How can I use the Bloomberg API with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, bloomberg, blpapi

I would like to connect to Bloomberg - data stream of stock quotations to our trading system written in Delphi.

The API libraries provided for download on the Bloomberg website (http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/) do not include a version specific for Delphi.

Is there a way to access the Bloomberg API from Delphi if only C/C++, Java, .Net, Perl and Python libraries are available?

Answer (score 2):

You can use without any problem the C/C++ SDK and map function calls into Delphi with the external keyword . Take a look at [this example](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm) for more information .

However as someone stated in the comments since the API you are talking about just embed calls to a web service, you could just call the web service from Delphi or define your own API on Delphi based on the web service spec. You can just have a look at the source of the C/C++ and try yo convert it to Delphi.

If calling directly the web service or converting the the API to Delphi is not an option for you, you can just use the C/C++ API as external functions call.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Bloomberg API, but from a quick look, it seems to include a Web Service, which a Delphi app ought in principle to be able to consume directly?

Comment: Yes, of course. I don't have looked at the library itself, but since it have a C/C++ SDK is suggested to use it ...

Comment: `You can just have a look at the source of the C/C++` - is the source available? I can see only binary files, or in case of Python/Perl the need to import the dynamic library (DLL).

Comment: @MartynA I don't think it calls a web service and the code is definitely not available.

Comment: @assylias:  Sure, I wasn't expecting code to be available, if you mean source code.  I can't see any explicit indication in the API Pdf, whether it includes a web service offering or not.  Anyway, the only point of my comment was that if it *does* include a web service, Delphi should be able to interact with that directly.

Comment: Directly using the web service, and converting the API libraries to Delphi, can get hard if there is no web service specification in the documentation. Calling into existing C API implementations from Delphi might be easier, as there is documentation and illustrative example code (for other languages).

Comment: The Bloomberg API is most definitely *not* a Web API, and the libraries we distribute don't 'wrap' a Web API. This does indeed limit consumption on some platforms, but as @aleroot said it's usually straightforward to use the C/C++ library from within those platforms as supporting external C libraries is a very common feature.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if I encounter the need to consume a web service where Delphi integration is not easy, I recommend to write a thin 'proxy' with one of the available SDKs.

Communication between the proxy and the Delphi side then can be implemented using simple file transfer, or a network protocol (such as HTTP).

In this case it could be:

```
(Bloomberg) <== Java SDK ==> (Java proxy) <== HTTP ==> (Delphi application)
```

The key advantage is that a first protoype can be implemented very quick, because all required parts are already present:

- download SDK and create a Java web service (server) project
- create small Delphi prototype which sends a HTTP request using Indy
- in the Java web service, map the request parameters to a BB API call
- map BB API call response to a Java web service response
- read response in Delphi application